# Adding a Sum in fractal collection meta data

Tags: php, laravel

how can I iterate over all items from collection to get a sum of a key in objects?

```
$data = fractal()
            ->collection($items, new ItemTransformer())
            ->paginateWith(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator))
            ->addMeta([
                'from' => $from->toDateString(),
                'till' => $till->toDateString(),
            ])
            ->toArray();
```

in addMeta() i want to include a 'total_sum' of all items->price->value.

when i add it like this:

```
$totalSum = $items->sum(function($item){
    return $item->price->sum('value);
}

    $data = fractal()
                ->collection($items, new ItemTransformer())
                ->paginateWith(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator))
                ->addMeta([
                    'from' => $from->toDateString(),
                    'till' => $till->toDateString(),
                    'total_sum' => $totalSum,
                ])
                ->toArray();
```

it does not iterate over the collection, but over all values in items table.

Comment: We have a map function on collection, you can use this to iterate over laravel collections. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

```
$sum = 0;
$totalPrice = $items->price;
foreach($totalPrice as $key=>$value){

if(isset($value->value))   
    $sum += $value->value;
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: Yes this was my first approach, but it seems a bit hacky. I think there must be some elegant method for it.

Comment: @MichaelPloeckinger perhaps try $sum = array_sum((array)$items->price->value);

Comment: @MichaelPloeckinger Maybe a bit 'hacky' but definitely not bad practice

Answer (score 0):

My current approach:

```
        $seller = $this->sellerRepository->findOrFail($id);
        $query = $seller->items()->whereHas('baseItem');
        $totalSum = $query->get()->sum(function ($item) {
                return $item->baseItem->price->value;
            });
        $paginator = $query->paginate($request->get('_perPage', $this->sellerRepository->getPerPage()));
        $items = $paginator->items();

        $data = fractal()
            ->collection($items, new ItemTransformer())
            ->paginateWith(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($paginator))
            ->addMeta([
                'from' => $from->toDateString(),
                'till' => $till->toDateString(),
                'total_sum' => $totalSum,
                'page_sum' => collect($items)->sum(function ($item) {
                        return $item->baseItem->price->value;
                    }),
            ])
            ->toArray();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Thanks for your hints.